# Polymer not reevaluating array-bound expression

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have the following excerpt which should be displayed if there are no elements in an array:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[isEmpty(arrayList)]]">
    <p>some text</p>
</template>
```

The element has the following methods:

```
<script>
(function() {
  'use strict';

  Polymer({
    ...

    properties: {
      arrayList: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {return []}
      }
    },

    ...

    _addElement: function(obj) {
      this.push('arrayList', obj);
    },

    isEmpty: function(obj) {
      return obj.length === 0;
    }

  });
})();
</script>
```

When I invoke `_addElement_`, it appears the `[[isEmpty(arrayList)]]` expression is not evaluated and consequently the text is not displayed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the expression to `[[isEmpty(arrayList.*)]]` or `[[isEmpty(arrayList.splices)]]`.
Otherwise, the `isEmpty` function will only be called if you assign a new array to `arrayList`, but not when you change its content. You can find more information in the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation).